# drop down list values not store in Database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

Dropdown list values get in database. 
But getting values again store mean not stored in database.
this is one registration form like department values get db.
But choosen values not stored in DB

```
<input class="form-last-name form-control" list="browsers" placeholder="Choose Dept"  id="dept" required/>
<datalist id="browsers">    
<option <?php
include "connect.php";
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT department FROM department");
$query_display = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT department FROM department");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
   {
     echo "<option value='". $row['department']."'>".$row['department'] .'</option>';
 }
   ?> ></option>
   </datalist>  
   </div>
```

register.php

```
    <?php
     include "connect.php";
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
     {
        $dept   = $_POST["dept"];
     $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO employee (Department)
            VALUES ('$dept')");

    if($result)
        {
            echo "<script>alert('New employee register successfully!')     </script>";
            echo "<script>window.open('register.php','_self')</script>";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Becuase your elemnt not have name

```
<input name='dept' class="form-last-name form-control" list="browsers" placeholder="Choose Dept"  id="dept" required/>
```

Comment: But first values only stored in output 
if other values selected but first values only stored. any one help me